# EditText full screen design in Android application

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I need user to enter password for WiFi network. When user press on EditText, it becomes full screen and now it looks like this:
[image]

I want to customize background color and text color of this view. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my xml for EditText:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: are you speaking about the textview or the keyboard?

Comment: Can you paste the XML that you are using for your layout? Looks like you just need to wrap_content and set maxLines on it

Comment: you can use backgound and textColor attributes to customize the look. Did you tried that?

Comment: @user2469133 I am speaking about textView

Comment: @BenPearson I have updated my post with xml

Comment: @noundla Yeah, of course I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a style:

```
<style name="Your.EditText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

then use

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
style="@style/Your.EditText.Style"

>

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

In your style, you can set the background colour and the text colour.